# Procedure with parameters: Draw a line (pascal)

Tags: pascal, freepascal

I want to make a program in pascal that calculates the sum of 2 numbers. I also want that program to draw a line between the number 2 and the total (of the two numbers). The user have to choose the size and symbol of the line, he wants to draw. This is what i have at the moment:

```
Program oef1;
Uses CRT;
VAR number1,number2,total:real;
procedure drawline(size:integer;symbol:char);
     VAR i:integer;
     begin
          FOR i:= 1 to size do write(symbol)
     end;



begin
     readln(number1,number2);

     writeln(number1:10:3);
     writeln(number2:10:3);
     drawline;
     writeln;
     total:=number1+number2;
     writeln(total:10:3);
     drawline;
     readkey();
end.
```

Comment: Clearly if you write `drawline` to accept two parameters, you have to actually pass those two parameters to it when it's called. You don't have a `char` declared anywhere to pass as the second value (the `symbol` parameter). You'd call it with `drawline(number1, '*');` to write a line of `*` characters, for instance.

Comment: it took me a while to understand, but i finally got it :p
Thanks for your help

Answer (score -1):

Drawline currently draws a string of `symbol`s `size` long. It requires two parameters, for example,

```
drawline(total, '-');
```

Maybe there should be a readln statement for the symbol, then you could call it with that variable.

Comment: Personally I would use '-' and not "-". Double quotes are not Pascal.

Comment: Oops. It's been a few years.